# multiple joined query with propel

Tags: database, zend-framework, orm, propel

Let's consider following tables:

```
 special_product(
  id
 product_key - FK to product.key)

 product(
 id
 key
 name)

product_attributes(
id
product_id FK to product.id
description
)
```

My question is how could I write a query that would provide me columns special_product.id, product.id, product_attributes.description starting from the `SpecialProductQuery` class.

Basically the generated query should be

```
select s.id, p.id, pa.description 
from special_product s
left join product p on s.key = p.key
left join product_attributes pa on p.id = pa.product_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you've got the relationships build out in your schema you should just be able to do:

```
 $specialProduct = specialProductQuery::create()
      ->joinWithProduct(SpecialProduct.Product)
      ->joinWith(Product.ProductAttributes)
      ->find();
```

From here you can get whichever of the values you need from the sub-objects (keep in mind you still need to iterate through the collection):

```
 foreach($specialProduct as $special)
 {
      $product = $special->getProduct();
 }
```

YMMV depending on how you've named out your model.